# Stuck in Keelhaul Key

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

I was going through Keelhaul Key a second time, with Ms. Mowz, to get all hidden things (Shine Sprites and Star Pieces) but I got stuck in the cave where you find the 50-something stranded Toads. On my second run, the switches in the background are missing, and there are no barrels between the paper boat platform and the rightmost ledge; therefore I cannot exit this area. If I get back to the left, there are no paper boat platforms either, since I came from the waterfall.

Can anyone confirm this bug? FYI in my current game, I just finished the Poshley Heights chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can indeed confirm this is "NOT" a bug as I have just experienced it myself and there is a way to escape if you get yourself in this predicament. If you go turn into the boat and return past the waves going backwards you can return to where you pick up the crank the first time when you're in chapter 5. Then you can jump back across and you are not softlocked anymore.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have the game anymore but I trust your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the plane platform to fly as far as you can to reach the right side of the area.

(I cannot confirm whether this works right now, but it's the only thing I can think of.)

Comment: The farthest I can go with the plane (and I'm quite good with it) is just past the stranded boat. I really think it's a bug and that nothing can be done. I had to reset the game. Thank god there were no save blocks in this area.

Answer (score 1):

From the lack of answers, I assume this is indeed a bug. I have no idea how it occurred though.